# How can I shift rows by one when they match a substring?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Could someone please help me solve this?

Attached is the example sheet of what I am trying to do:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12w4rGArGi1I1wlpm5yJJtT5AAlMM4LcZC31_DpP6jZQ/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to shift the rows that contain "PO" in my data selection. (see shift function)

It should change from this:

[image: example1]

to this:

[image]

I have written a script but it isn't working and I am not getting an error message.

I have a feeling it is because I am trying to "+1" my array to offset my values. Please help!

Here is my current script:

```
function shift() {
  try{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var as = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var ar = as.getActiveRange();
    var vals = ar.getValues();                              // get values from the active (selected) range...... intended use is to draw a selection where the PO BOX substring is in the leftmost column
    //  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(vals);                 //for checking values
    var r;                                                  // variable for rows

    for (r = 0; r < vals.length; r++){                      // for each row, up to the last row (iterate over all rows from top to bottom)
      if(vals[r][0].indexOf("PO") != -1){                   // if first column in each row contains "PO"
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("found a PO BOX");     // make annoucement
        var c;                                              // variable for columns
        var cols = [];                                      // array for column data (for debugging)
        for (c = 0; c < vals[r].length; c++){               // for each columns in row (iterating over each cell in row from left to right)
          cols[c] = vals[r][c];                             // add the current cell value to an array 
          vals[r][c+1] = vals[r][c];                        // take the value from the current cell and assign it to the next cell (+1 to the column)
        }
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(cols);                 // show me the data that cas changed

      }
    }
    ar.setValues(vals);                                     // set new values to active range
  }
  catch(err){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

Expectations:

1. get the data range (my intended testing range is B:1 to D:12)
2. iterate through each row, and on each row, iterate through each
   cell(column)
3. If the very first cell in the current row(vals[r][0]) contains the
   substring "PO" , then I want to change the values of that row such
   that they all shift over by one column, and leave the very first
   cell as a blank string
4. I change the values by replacing the current values with the same
   values BUT +1 to the columns row(vals[r][c]) = row(vals[r][c+1])

Realit(EDIT)y:

Exceeded memory limit error... possible infinite loop happening... i THINK it might be because I am adding a column that does not exist in the data range, but how would I get around this problem?

SOLVED!!!!

After much trial and error, I cane up with an answer (posted int he answers)

feels great to solve my own problem for the first time ever!

Comment: @I'-'I I am working on some edits to clarify. thanks.

Comment: okay I fixed it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was exactly what i expected. I was trying to assign values outside of the range.

The way that I solved this was to assign all of my values to an array(I also shifted them over in the process), and then loop through the range(the range is just a two dimensional array), assigning all of the shifted values to the range columns.

```
function shift() {
  try{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var as = ss.getActiveSheet();                     
    var ar = as.getActiveRange();
    var vals = ar.getValues();
    var r; //variable for rows

    for (r = 0; r < vals.length; r++){                                           // for each row, up to the last row (iterate over all rows from top to bottom)
      if((vals[r][0].indexOf("PO") != -1)||(vals[r][0].indexOf("P0") != -1)){    // if first column in each row contains "PO"
        var c; // variable for columns                                                    
        var cols = []; // array to store all data temporarily (will be uses to set new values later)
        for (c = 0; c < vals[r].length; c++){                                   // then iterate over each column(cell) in the row
          if(c == 0){                                                           // if it is the first row,
            cols[c+1] = vals[r][c];                                             // assign second index of the array with the PO value (to simulate a shift)
            cols[c] = "";                                                       // assign the first index of the array a blank string
          }
          else{                                                                 // if it is not the first row
            cols[c+1] = vals[r][c];                                             // assign each additional column value to the next index (+1) of the array
          }
        }
        for (c = 0; c < vals[r].length; c++){                                   // once the array is finished, loop through the columns again foreach row
          vals[r][c] = cols[c];                                                 // this time, assigning the new values to the corresponding array indices
        }
      }
    }
    ar.setValues(vals);                                                         // now, set the values that you reassinged to the array
  }
  catch(err){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: @I'-'I key points on top. explanation in the comments. is that good?